# How can I change default font for other language?

Tags: language, fonts

I use English as my default language and I can change the system font just fine, but I also use Thai language and I don't like the current font how can I change it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great to see a fellow Thai in here.

Now as for the font, I assume you want to change it to Thai serif font. 
Elementary OS come with both san-serif and serif Thai fonts. All you need to do is change the default font from san-serif to serif. And you can do that by copying these font files:

- `/usr/share/fonts/truetype/noto/NotoSerifThai-Bold.ttf`
- `/usr/share/fonts/truetype/noto/NotoSerifThai-Regular.ttf`

to `~/.local/share/fonts/` And then refresh font caches with command `fc-cache` in the terminal.

You can use `fc-list :lang=th` to check if your font is registered.

Comment: Wow it works thank you very much :D !!